# RecyclerView height limits

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have created a `RecyclerView` and I had liked it to show a maximum of 3 items ~ 300dp.

If there are 4 items on the list, I had like to show 3 and the 4th to be scrollable.

If there are 2 items, I want it to be only in the size of 2 (~200dp).

Is there a way to define in my `.xml` something like:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxHeight="300dp"
```

So as long as the Recyclerview is less than 3 it will be `wrap_content` or `300dp` otherwise?

If there is a solution using `xml` then I prefer it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to make using only `layout.xml` file. What you can do, is to dynamically determine in your `ViewHolder` it's height and then pass it right to the top level. Before adapter is set - recalculate height of your `RecyclerView` to fit particular demands